# jquery resizable & draggable not working at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(function(){
        $("#a").draggable();        
        $("#a").resizable();
    }); 
});
</script>

<style>
img{border:solid 1px #000; width:512px; height:512px;}
</style>

<img id="a" src="images/1.png" />
```

I have an image use jquery resizable & draggable.

It's not working if I use both at same time.

Comment: included jquery-ui-css file?

Comment: yes include ui.css, ui.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Like

```
$('.draggable').draggable();

$('.resizable').resizable({
    aspectRatio: true,
    handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw'
});

$('.resizable').parent().rotatable();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/4Vfm5/802/)

Comment: so resizable & draggable can't be in the same element?

Comment: @user2178521, No we can use them within the same function.